# Kubernetes - Passing in environment variable and service name (from DNS)

Tags: kubernetes

I can't seem to find an example of the correct syntax for inserting a environment variable along with the service name:

So I have a service defined as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: test
```

I then use a secrets file with the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test
data:
  password: fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx787xx==
```

And just to confirm I'm using `envFrom` to set that password as an env variable:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test
          image: xxxxxxxxxxx
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: test
          - secretRef:
              name: test
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
```

Now in my config file I want to refer to that `password` as well as the service name itself - is this the correct way to do so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test
data:
  WORKING_URI: "http://somedomain:${password}@test"
```

Comment: Could you paste your Pod/Deployment file?

Comment: @fiunchinho updated above

Comment: While not an answer to the question - I find this flawed design. If you have to refer password/secret in COnfigmap - which means the secret must be created before config map (Order). Secondly - this also means your password will be stored in K8S etcd - which is a potential risk. I would suggest using something like Vault to get the password directly to the application. Check docs here: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/kubernetes.html

Answer (score 0):

The yaml configuration does not work the way you provided as an example.

If you want to setup Kubernetes with a complex configuration and
use variables or dynamic assignment to some of them, you have to
use an external parser to replace variable place holders. I use
bash and sed to accomplish  it. I changed your config a bit:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test
data:
  WORKING_URI: "http://somedomain:VAR_PASSWORD@test"
```

After saving, I created a simple shell script containing desired values.

```
#!/bin/sh

export PASSWORD="verysecretpwd"
cat deploy.yaml | sed "s/VAR_PASSWORD/$PASSWORD/g" | kubectl -f -
```